# ASP.NET Core 2 - AspNetRoleClaims

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I have started with an empty asp.net core 2 project and wanted to add features to it so that I can learn all of the pieces.  I have created a db out in azure that I am connecting to, and I have a dbContext in my project.  I am using the ASP.NET Core Identity, and I have successfully added the tables to the application.  I am trying to make a few changes in my database context and push this up to my database.  This is what I understand that needs to be done with "code first" in EF Core.  When I attempt to create a new migration in PMC, I get the error below.  I have no idea what this means.  Any thoughts on this?  How do I solve this?

TIA

Error Message:

Cannot use table 'AspNetRoleClaims' for entity type 'AspNetRoleClaims' since it is being used for entity type 'IdentityRoleClaim' and there is no relationship between the primary key {'Id'} and the primary key {'Id'}.

Source for my database context:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace PooperApp.Models
{
    public partial class PoopTheWorldContext : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
    {
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoleClaims> AspNetRoleClaims { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserRoles> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserTokens> AspNetUserTokens { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Clean> Clean { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PoopLocation> PoopLocation { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Province> Province { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance on storing connection strings.
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"......");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRoleClaims>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
                entity.HasIndex(e => e.RoleId);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Role)
                    .WithMany(p => p.AspNetRoleClaims)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRoles>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedName)
                    .HasName("RoleNameIndex")
                    .IsUnique()
                    .HasFilter("([NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL)");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.Property(e => e.Ipaddress).HasColumnName("IPAddress");

                entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(256);

                entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedName).HasMaxLength(256);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserClaims>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserId);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                    .WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserClaims)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserLogins>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.LoginProvider, e.ProviderKey });

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserId);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                    .WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserLogins)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserRoles>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.RoleId });

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.RoleId);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Role)
                    .WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserRoles)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                    .WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserRoles)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUsers>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedEmail)
                    .HasName("EmailIndex");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedUserName)
                    .HasName("UserNameIndex")
                    .IsUnique()
                    .HasFilter("([NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL)");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.Property(e => e.Email).HasMaxLength(256);

                entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedEmail).HasMaxLength(256);

                entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedUserName).HasMaxLength(256);

                entity.Property(e => e.UserName).HasMaxLength(256);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserTokens>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.LoginProvider, e.Name });

                entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                    .WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserTokens)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Clean>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.DateEntered).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.DateUpdated).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.Description).HasMaxLength(512);

                entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(50);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Country>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.DateEntered).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.DateUpdated).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.Description).HasMaxLength(512);

                entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.Property(e => e.AppleName).HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.Property(e => e.GoogleName).HasMaxLength(50);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<PoopLocation>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasIndex(e => e.AspNetUsersId);

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.PostalCode);

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.ProvinceId);

                entity.Property(e => e.Address1).HasMaxLength(100);

                entity.Property(e => e.Address2).HasMaxLength(100);

                entity.Property(e => e.City).HasMaxLength(100);

                entity.Property(e => e.DateEntered).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.DateUpdated).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.PostalCode).HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.AspNetUsers)
                    .WithMany(p => p.PoopLocation)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.AspNetUsersId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_PoopLocation_AspNetUsersId");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Clean)
                    .WithMany(p => p.PoopLocation)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CleanId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_PoopLocation_CleanId");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Province)
                    .WithMany(p => p.PoopLocation)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProvinceId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_PoopLocation_ProvinceId");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Province>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasIndex(e => e.CountryId);

                entity.Property(e => e.Abbreviation).HasMaxLength(5);

                entity.Property(e => e.AppleName).HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.Property(e => e.DateEntered).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.DateUpdated).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.Description).HasMaxLength(512);

                entity.Property(e => e.GoogleName).HasMaxLength(10);

                entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Country)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Province)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CountryId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Province_Country");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you create your own `AspNetRoleClaims` class? If yes, can you show its implementation?

Comment: No, I didn't.  I used everything from the asp.net core identity framework.

Comment: Are you sure? I just went to the ASP.NET Core Identity project on GitHub and didn't find any class `AspNetRoleClaims`, only tables with that name. Maybe you have some old test class?

See: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=AspNetRoleClaims

Comment: Just remove the AspNet.... DbSet and you should be fine

Comment: I think where my confusion is that I initially got the identity tables to be created, and then I created my dbcontext, so I had my workflow wrong.  At my heart, I'm a database guy, so it made sense to create the tables first and then get them to be recreated in the context.  I think I have my workflow right now, so I am going to try this again this morning (at least it is morning to me).  :-)

Comment: I know it is too late to respond to the post. If you are still learning. I recommend looking into ASP.CORE 2.1 lot of things are changed. Also, try using the documentation on Microsoft website to understand the basics and create a project as directed. This will help you get started with the basics address.

Answer (score 12):

The problem may be caused because your class `AspNetRoleClaims` is not correctly inherited from `IdentityRoleClaim`. It has its own configuration from generic class `TRoleClaim` to the table `AspNetRoleClaims`:

```
builder.Entity<TRoleClaim>(b =>
{
    b.HasKey(rc => rc.Id);
    b.ToTable("AspNetRoleClaims");
});
```

So, if you don't show  the correct type to the constructor, it is going to use its own implementation of `IdentityRoleClaim` which is diferent of your `AspNetRoleClaims` class.
In this case, you are trying to create the same table with a diferent class.

To resolve the problem, try use the constructor giving all generic types it requires:

```
public partial class PoopTheWorldContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, 
    ApplicationRole, Guid, AspNetUserClaims, AspNetUserRoles, AspNetUserLogins, 
    AspNetRoleClaims, AspNetUserTokens>
{
    //your code here
}
```

You have to do the same inheritance you did to `ApplicationUser` and `ApplicationRole` to use `Guid` key in all the other classes.

```
public class AspNetUserTokens : IdentityUserToken<Guid>{ /*your code here*/ }
public class AspNetRoleClaims : IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>{ /*your code here*/ }
public class AspNetUserLogins : IdentityUserLogin<Guid>{ /*your code here*/ }
public class AspNetUserRoles : IdentityUserRole<Guid>{ /*your code here*/ }
public class AspNetUserClaims : IdentityUserClaim<Guid>{ /*your code here*/ }
```

And, finally, you don't need to create all these DbSet unless you desire give them another name because they are already declared in base class. For example, `AspNetRoleClaims` is declared as `RoleClaims`. And, besides that, you should use `DbSet<ApplicationUser> AspNetUsers` and `DbSet<ApplicationRole> AspNetRoles` instead of `DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles` and `DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers` because these were the classes you passed the base class. If you don't do that, you'll receive the same error you're trying to avoid.

If you want to see DbSet declarations and tables configurations:

[IdentityDbContext](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/980206cc260a438b390ca5154fee6ea236b171bc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityDbContext.cs)

[IdentityUserContext](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/980206cc260a438b390ca5154fee6ea236b171bc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityUserContext.cs)

Comment: that makes sense.  I'll definitely give this a try.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solving removing all `public virtual DbSet` AspNetUsers Identities of Context file:

...

```
 public partial class ...MyContext : IdentityDbContext


public MyContext (DbContextOptions<MyContext > options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    //public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoleClaims> AspNetRoleClaims { get; set; }
    //public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    //public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    //public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserRoles> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because a template for this table already exists.
Try to do it this way. It worked for me.

public DbSet<IdentityRoleClaim< string >>

The code above solves the problem but one important thing to remember: If the class inherits the IdentityDbContext there is no need to include the DbSet because the Entity Framework Design will understand that the tables must be created.

internal class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext